# Google AppEngine not able to read file in production mode

Tags: google-app-engine

In local development mode, I can read from a ~7.4MB file in my war/ directory into an object, using the following code (with all the try/catch stuff removed)

```
FileInputStream fis;            
fis = new FileInputStream("myObject.dat");              
ObjectInputStream ois;          
ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);                   
myObject  = (ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<float[]>>>) ois.readObject(); //-- ! prod mode gets stuck here! but dev mode is fine
```

In local development mode, it works great and reads the object in a few seconds.

When I deploy to AppEngine, I get time-out errors reading the file. It finds the file and starts reading, but can't finish in time.  Here's some of the error stack:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
>   ...
>   Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This
>   request (...) started at 2012/06/21 02:19:57.368 UTC and was still
>   executing at 2012/06/21 02:20:56.928 UTC.      at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.read(Native Method) ...

When I make the "myObject.dat" file smaller, it works in production mode, so the code itself is fine, it's just that GAE can't read the larger file fast enough like my local mode can!  How can a GAE server be slower than my little local machine?

Comment: Pop quiz: Google is known for a) Having datacenters with very few, extremely powerful and expensive computers that do huge amounts of work and are far faster than your development machine, b) Having datacenters with many commodity machines, relying on distributing load and redundancy to do their job

Comment: How does this help Nick?

Comment: Nick, you can see my comment in the accepted answer below.  I don't think it had anything to do with Google data-center machines being commodity level machines.  I'm quite sure my $400 retail simple home machine is not as powerful as a Google commodity machine, and this was proved when I used Peter's suggestion.

Comment: Java serialization is indeed slow, but what I was addressing was your expectation that individual processes should be faster just by virtue of running on App Engine. Yes, an individual machine is probably faster than your desktop - but unlike your desktop, it's serving a lot of apps and a lot of requests at the same time. The power of App Engine is its ability to scale across many machines horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java serialization (e.g. `ObjectInputStream`) is not a standardized way to store objects: it is not guaranteed to work across different JVM implementations or even between different versions of the same JVM.

Use some other more standardized way to store object data: JSON and XML for example. You might also fing [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) useful.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Even if the standarization ends up being a problem (which is solvable by doing the ObjectOutputStream on the same JVM), for now **I have a more fundamental problem:**  the file is read too slowly in GAE (and therefore the timeout error), but much faster (a few seconds) in my local mode.  Why so slow in GAE?

Comment: See nicks pop quizz above.  The servers you run on in production are slower, and shared.  Plus the filesystem you are reading on is an virtual filesystem layered on other infrastructure and is slower and can be very slow if something else is going on in google land.

Comment: In the end, when I replaced the Java serialization with my own proprietary text file serialization, I was able to read the file in to the object very quickly in Google land, as quick as on my local machine.  So it may be as Peter first suspected:  the Java serialization was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at how much memory is consumed in your development environment when you read the file and instantiate objects that way, comparing that to the class of front-end instance that you have configured?

The development appserver doesn't attempt to simulate the memory sizes of the various class of frontends.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  What do you mean by "comparing that to the class of front-end instance"?

Comment: You have a bit of control over how much RAM is available to your deployed app. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

I was suggesting looking at your dev-time RAM requirements to see if they're a match for the front-end class you're using.